# Load Testing using JMeter on Magento Application

Tags: magento, jmeter, load-testing

I still trying how to setup load testing using JMeter on Magento application. Any of you guys have experience on it?

At the moment I have problem on formkey initialization, for example when I try to make checkout scenario:

1. First, do user signin
2. Add product to cart
3. Then, do checkout

I have been used HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier, I set session argument name as "formkey", but It doesn't work.

Sorry I can't specific my question.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I recall, the parameter should be `form_key`. Double check you correctly retrieve its value via [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination (see [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for more information on how to get to the bottom of unexpected test script behaviour).

Also I don't think you need the URL ReWriting Modifier.

Refer [JMeter Magento Login Test Plan](http://pastebin.com/t00RaVvH) as example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply body. ;)

I have solved my previous problem on managing cookie (formkey). I set CookieManager.save.cookies as true, then I call cookie as variable on test plan using ${COOKIE_cookiename}. In my situation, I call ${COOKIE_formkey} to get formkey cookie, then I put on the path of http request.